# How can you find out the currently logged in user in the OS X GUI?

Tags: macos, login, user-accounts

Trying to find out if a particular user is logged into the machine, specifically the user *using* the graphical user interface.

Is this possible via command line?

Comment: Wait GUI and command line? Both? Or just command line? I'm confused.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex, made the question more clear for you.

Comment: :D that's great!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

GUI:

- Open the Accounts preference pane in *System Preferences*. The pre-selected user account will be the active user account.
- If fast user switching is active its menu extra (the menu on the right side of the menu bar) can be configured to show the name of the active user.

Command Line:

- Check the owner of `/dev/console`

  ```
  stat -f '%u %Su' /dev/console
  ```
- Write a program that uses the official API ([SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific/Reference/reference.html); see below)

In a C program:

The C code in [Technical Q&A QA1133:
Determining console user login status](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1133.html)
 shows how to determine which user owns the active GUI session.

For example:

```
/* Adapted from QA1133:
 *    http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1133.html
 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SCDynamicStoreRef store;
    CFStringRef name;
    uid_t uid;
#define BUFLEN 256
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    Boolean ok;

    store = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, CFSTR("GetConsoleUser"), NULL, NULL);
    assert(store != NULL);
    name = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(store, &uid, NULL);
    CFRelease(store);

    if (name != NULL) {
        ok = CFStringGetCString(name, buf, BUFLEN, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        assert(ok == true);
        CFRelease(name);
    } else {
        strcpy(buf, "<none>");
    }

    printf("%d %s\n", uid, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See manpage getlogin.

Comment: stat -f '%u %Su' /dev/console works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: why not just `whoami`?

Answer (score 8):

Via the command line, `who` and `users` should work.

Comment: Ah, `who` and look for "console". Thanks.

Comment: @Gerald: Using `who` is not accurate on my 10.4 system when using fast user switching (the system I am using right now shows another user on “console” even though my GUI session is the active one). Maybe it is more reliable in newer versions.

Comment: @JohnT: if you have 2 users logged in (user switching), the who command will list both the users associated with 'console'. This does not work correctly.