# How to find out if a user is logged into OSX locally?

Tags: macos, automation

This question is similar to [How can you find out the currently logged in user in the OS X GUI?](https://superuser.com/questions/180819/how-can-you-find-out-the-currently-logged-in-user-in-the-os-x-gui) but with a twist.

I am trying to launch the iOS simulator for automated testing, but the simulator will refuse to launch unless the user is logged in locally (i.e. has an active GUI session). It does not matter if the user switched to another profile, so long as he/she is still logged in.

**How do I check, from an SSH session, if a user is logged in locally?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgrep -u userId /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/MacOS/SystemUIServer` seems to do the job.

This process is run when a user logs in locally, and is killed when he/she logs off.

Comment: @Juza, post a separate question. This isn't the place to ask.

Comment: @Juza, fine. But please delete your comments. They are cluttering this answer with an unrelated discussion.